# Using IEBCOPY to copy members to datasets with wild cards

Tags: mainframe, jcl

So we're upgrading SEASOFT Fastpack and have to add members to everyone's ISPF profile to allow the usage of the product's menu.

The ideal JCL we're after is as follows:

```
//COPYRGHT JOBCARD              
//JOBSTEP  EXEC  PGM=IEBCOPY                          
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=A                               
//INDD     DD  DSNAME=FASTPACK.SRC,        
//             DISP=SHR,UNIT=SYSDA                    
//OUTDD    DD  DSNAME=BFCU.PRODISPF.PROF&SYSNAME..&USERID     <==== ? BFCU.PRODISPF.PROF*.*
//             DISP=SHR,UNIT=SYSDA                    
//SYSIN DD *                                          
  COPY INDD=OUTDD,OUTDD=OUTDD                         
  COPY INDD=((INDD,R)),OUTDD=OUTDD                    
/*
```

Obviously it would be nice if we can make the job dynamically look for all the datasets that match the pattern.

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea to compress the ISPF profile data set when users might be logged in, or will you run this job during a maintenance window? Are you really still allocating those profile data sets as PDS not PDSE?

Comment: Do you have a logon program in place, i.e. some REXX or CLIST that is run when the user logs into TSO/ISPF? If so, you could add some code to check for the members and copy if not found. Do you allow users to log in from multiple systems simultaneously? If so, make sure the user is not logged on on multiple systems, notify if he/she is, and delay to copy until it is the only log-in (this is only important if the data sets are *not* PDSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing Rexx or clist code to use the LMDINIT and LMDLIST ISPF services to create a list of datasets matching your pattern and save the list in a dataset.  Then write another program to read that list of datasets and write your desired JCL, one step per dataset.  Run the Rexx or clist code in ISPF in batch.

You will want to count how many steps you generate, as a job can only have 255 steps.

You can make this as automated as you like, for example you could generate a jobcard, an instream proc containing your IEBCOPY with the OUTDD DSN a parameter, and then each step executes the instream proc with the DSN parameter set to the dataset name.  When you get to 255 steps, generate another jobcard, another copy of the instream proc, and continue with generating steps.

Comment: If you are using **Rexx**, you might as well use `ISPF File tailoring` to create the JCL. You could write a new job statement after 255 data set

Comment: @cschneid: You're right. I have moved the commens to the original question. Thanks for pointing out.